# Angular unit testing - change component variable inside the test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test the functionality of a button, but that element is not visible on the page because it's under an `*ngIf`. I would like to set the variable from `*ngIf` to be truthy in order to be able to display the data. I tried doing it with:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.currentUser = {firstName: 'xxx'} as User; // Changing currentUser so it won't be undefined anymore 
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

but still doesn't work. Here is my component:

```
<div class="menu-button-container">
    <div class="menu-button" [ngClass]="{'menu-open': isMenuOpen}" (click)="toggleMenu()" *ngIf="currentUser">
        <div class="line-menu-button line-menu-button__top"></div>
        <div class="line-menu-button line-menu-button__middle"></div>
        <div class="line-menu-button line-menu-button__bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the test I try to run:

```
it('should open the menu when the button menu is clicked', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const menuDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.menu-button'));
    expect(menuDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

this always fails. If I define the `*ngIf` rule as `*ngIf="currentUser"`, the test is working. How can I do this variable change from the test? Please advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the value of the currentUser variable:

```
it('should open the menu when the button menu is clicked', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
  const component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.currentUser = true;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  const menuDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.menu-button'));
  expect(menuDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I created an entire test and it works for me

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestTComponent } from './test-t.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

fdescribe('TestTComponent', () => {
  let component: TestTComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestTComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    component.currentUser = true;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const menuDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.menu-button'));
    expect(menuDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I get the same error as before: `Expected null to be truthy`.

Comment: whenever you change or modify the component class property you need to add this line: fixture.detectChanges();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixture.detectChanges(); triggers change detaction cycle and when you read value from html component not finished to update itself.

You solve using "whenStable()" function

```
  it('should open the menu when the button menu is clicked', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component.currentUser = true;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable()
        .then(() => {
            const menuDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.menu-button'));
            expect(menuDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
        });
    
  });
```